# Populate a multidimensional object with an unknown string array

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array

Assume I have an unknown string array such as:

```
arr = [fruit/bananas:10, fruit/apples/0:5, fruit/apples/1:8, fruit/apples/2:7, car/honda/civic:1];
```

and I want to populate an object such that each array value is a path to its object value (ie arr becomes obj below):

```
obj = {
      'fruits' :{
               'bananas' : 10,
               'apples'  : [5,8,7]
       },
       'car'   :{
               'honda':{
                       'civic': 1
                }
       }
};
```

I am just wondering what type of recursive function would be best since the actual array length for each value is unknown so just splitting '/' and populating wouldn't work (that I could figure out)

Comment: Every recursion can be written as a loop (and in this case, even a quite trivial one). What have you tried? Please show us your attempt ([edit] the code into the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = ['fruit/bananas:10', 'fruit/apples/0:5', 'fruit/apples/1:8', 'fruit/apples/2:7', 'car/honda/civic:1'];

function createObject(array) {
    var out = {};
    array.forEach(function(value) {
        var current = out,
            last = current,
            data = value.split(':'),
            keys = data[0].split('/'),
            lastKey = keys.pop();

        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if(!current[key]) {
                current[key] = {};
            }
            last = current;
            current = current[key];
        });
        if(lastKey === '0') {
            current = last[keys.pop()] = [];
        }
        current[lastKey] = +data[1];
    });
    return out;
}

console.log(createObject(arr));
```

Here is the **[jsfiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xa039xj3/3/)**